# お願いね used in this script

Tags: translation, words, expressions, sentence

In this script:

類の母:
ごめんね、類。
寧々ちゃんのことよろしくね

幼い類:
大丈夫だよ。
ふたりとも、いってらっしゃい

類の母:
うん。お願いね、類

What does お願いね mean here? Is she asking him to take care of Nene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, she's simply reiterating the request made in the first line (「寧々ちゃんのことよろしくね」).